# JSF / Primefaces selectBooleanCheckbox component in dataTable always unchecked

Tags: java, jsf, checkbox, primefaces, facelets

In my project i'm using JSF 2.0 and Primefaces 3.5.

In one page i have a `p:dataTable` and the tables one column has `selectBooleanCheckbox`. I tried both of `p:selectBooleanCheckbox` and `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`. My code like as follow:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="false" />
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="true" />
            <p:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{bean.items}" var="item" paginator="false">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.value}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="white-space:normal; text-align: center;">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="#{item.checked}" />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="true" />
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="false" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="true" />
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="false" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
```

And the result:

[image: primefaces jsf selectBooleanCheckbox]

I want to show correct case of selectBooleanCheckbox. Any suggestions?

Comment: While navand answer is right to fulfill your needs, I don't understand why you haven't bound the value of the `selectBooleanCheckbox` to an attribute of your `#{item}` var.

Comment: I found my mistake. In above code (sample snippet) i used `value="#{item.checked}"` but in my real code i have used `value="item.checked"`. Now i'm using `value="#{item.checked}"` and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to be linking the checkbox to any value in your backing bean. Try storing the value in your backing bean and having it be reflected in your checkbox. For instance,

Backing Bean:

```
private Boolean value1 = true;
private Boolean value2 = false;

//appropriate getters and setters for the above values
```

JSF Page Fragment:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{backingbean.value1}" itemLabel="Value 1"/>
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{backingbean.value2}" itemLabel="Value 2"/>
```

This should result in the first checkbox being checked (because value1 = true) and the second should not be as value2 = false. In this manner, whenever you click a checkbox it's value will also be reflected in value1 and value2 respectively.

Hope that helps...

Also, @navand is correct in saying to use #{true} and #{false} if you want to manually set the checkbox to be checked or not.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `#{true}` or `#{false}` instead of `true` or `false`
like this:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="#{true}" />
```

Comment: I works when i use this: `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="id" value="true" />` outside the dataTable?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know exactly why, if i found it, say to you.